# Error in installing mod_dav_svn

Tags: svn, centos, mod-dav-svn

I am trying to install mod_dav_svn module in vps. I have already installed subversion.

But when I am installing mod_dav_svn, I am getting following error:

```
ea-apache24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.15-54.el6.centos.x86_64
```

The full response is:

```
[admin@vps ~]# yum install mod_dav_svn
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, tsflags, universal-hooks
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 67.222.0.10
 * base: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: mirror.steadfast.net
 * updates: mirror.steadfast.net
EA4                                                      | 2.9 kB     00:00 ...
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00
extras                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mod_dav_svn.x86_64 0:1.6.11-15.el6_7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 for package: mod_dav_svn-1.6.11-15.el6_7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package httpd.x86_64 0:2.2.15-54.el6.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-tools = 2.2.15-54.el6.centos for package: httpd-2.2.15-54.el6.centos.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package httpd-tools.x86_64 0:2.2.15-54.el6.centos will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: ea-apache24-2.4.23-3.3.1.cpanel.x86_64 conflicts httpd-mmn
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: ea-apache24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.15-54.el6.centos.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Please help as I am not a pro. Thanks.